# AWS educate account but sage maker gives error while training a model

Tags: amazon-web-services

I made an AWS educate account but sage maker gives me an error while training a model:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: User: arn:aws:sts::387322780008:assumed-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20200830T040703/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:387322780008:training-job/xgboost-2020-08-29-20-06-24-680 with an explicit deny
```

Did any one know the solution

Answer (score 1):

The error you’re seeing is an explicit deny which means that the IAM permissions attached are denying that action.

Looking at the [availability of AWS educate](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf) ensure that you’re creating the resources in us-east-1 and that the instance type is one of the following:

- ml.t2.medium
- ml.t2.large
- ml.t3.medium
- ml.t3.large

If both of these conditions are met and you still cannot access then you should reach out to AWS support to validate why you do not have the necessary permissions for your classroom.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Educate accounts are intentionally limited in their capabilities.

For any enquiries regarding AWS Education accounts, you will need to **contact AWS Educate directly**: [AWS Educate | Contact Us](https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/)